# convert string to datetime which handle all different formats in c# for excel and csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am trying to read data from excel which has date in different formats .

- 7/10/2019  3:03:01 PM

  ```
  7/10/2019  13:03:12

  7/10/2019  3:07
  ```

Also tried with below code
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(sDate, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate))

it worked for few but not for all formats

I'm Reading from excel file something like this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
{ 
    ob.id= dr[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Excel dates are stored as floating point numbers in the OADate format, not strings. You can parse them with [DateTime.FromOADate(Double)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=net-5.0). How are you reading the Excel sheet? Are you reading a real Excel sheet or a CSV? Post your actual code. Perhaps you should use a library like [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to read Excel data instead of trying to do this by hand

Comment: Reading from excel file something like this foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                            {
                              
                                ob.id= dr[0].ToString();

Comment: That's the bug - your converting the *date* into a string, then trying to read it back as a date. `dr[0]` is already a `DateTime`

Comment: I think if you you don't get positive response from "TryParsExact" , You can get dates as string and compare length of them, so you can choose how to cast specific date in a switch case.

Comment: Just cast the existing `DateTime` value to a `DateTime`: `(DateTime)dr[0]`. `DataRow.Item` returns the underlying value as an `object`, but the value retains its type. There's no reason to convert the DateTime into a string and back again

Answer (score 4):

The cell value is already a `DateTime` but the [DataRow indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_Int32_) returns it as an `object`. Calling `.ToString()` creates a new string using the DateTime value. Instead of trying to parse that string, just use the original value, either by casting:

```
DateTime date=(DateTime)dr[0];
```

You can also use the strongly-typed [Field<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_Int32_) accessor:

```
DateTime date=dr.Field<DateTime>(0);
```

Eg:

```
foreach(var row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable)
{
    var date = row.Field<DateTime>(0);
}
```

Comment: I'd add such of check: `DBNull.Value.Equals(dr[index])` to avoid errors while reading.

Comment: I tested with code it is working fine .Thanks for help . I am marking your answer as accepted .could you also add the code to Excel with ExcelDatareader.Currently I am using oledbconnection to read excel

Comment: Maciej... already checking that before converting date

Comment: It worked perfectly for one excel file .But other excel file it is giving error as Specified cast is not valid.The issue might be I have copied details from csv to excel.Please respond